# PyAudio stream_callback unexpected argument

Tags: python, portaudio, pyaudio

I’m currently developing a little project involving microphone input in Python and I’m using [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) library (binding for PortAudio).
As I try the first « Wire » example (blocking), everything work flawlessly, but as soon as I try running the second example, « Wire (callback) », Python says :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    stream_callback=callback)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream_callback'
```

While it is correctly defined in the binding. 
Any help on this ?

The complete code is :

```
import pyaudio
import time

WIDTH = 2
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(WIDTH),
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Thanks !

Comment: I took a glance at the docs, and the source thinking maybe that keyword 'stream_callback' was spelled incorrectly, but its not. Are you using latest pyaudio? I also noticed this is the example from their docs page. Did you copy-paste it?

Comment: I’m using the Debian Wheezy repositories version, I’ll try installing it from source. Yes, it is one of their examples.

Comment: You could also check the installed .py file in your site-packages folder, since the source file is in python too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating PyAudio and PortAudio solved the problem.

Comment: In particular, for ubuntu: `apt-get install portaudio19-dev && 
pip install --upgrade pyaudio` and for fedora, `yum install portaudio-devel` and then compile and install PyAudio from source

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like stream_callback in a valid arg on Mac OSX installations of PyAudio :(